# CQ5 DAM search by tags group

Tags: search, tags, aem, dam

I Have Tag structured like below:

```
companyname:Topic
    companyname:Topic/Articles
    companyname:Topic/videos
    companyname:Topic/casestrudies
```

On of the resource is taged as `companyname:Topic`. In the DAM content finder, if I check the checkbox of `companyname:Topic` and do the search, query parameter is excluding the `companyname:Topic` but all its sub tags are passed in the search Query. Because of which I am getting Zero result.

How to include `Grouptagid` also in the Query parameter?